# Filter container based on subquery from the same container

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to filter a container data based on existence of an ID with in the same container using a subquery.

Here is my query looks like

```sql
select d.pid
from MyContainer d 
where d.pid in (
   SELECT DISTINCT c.pid
   FROM MyContainer c
   WHERE c.ServiceName = 'myService'
   AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.Messages, {"ApiResponse":{"statusCode":400}}, true)
)
```

Its triggering an error

> Failed to query item for container MyContainer :  Message:
> {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":108,"end":114},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax
> error, incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'."}]}

But when I execute my subquery

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.pid
FROM MyContainer c
WHERE c.ServiceName = 'myService'
AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.Messages, {"ApiResponse":{"statusCode":400}}, true)
```

it returns

```
[
    {
        "processExecutionId": "fabf7364-bef7-4170-bdcf-9ee0cc8df077"
    },
    {
        "processExecutionId": "48576688-1331-4742-a885-447028462bfc"
    },
    {
        "processExecutionId": "05257306-538a-467f-a546-f57bc79d4074"
    },
    {
        "processExecutionId": "907c8136-fb56-42ee-8d63-ecfd9a26384a"
    },
    {
        "processExecutionId": "69bcc177-e573-4261-8f34-069496ec6e6f"
    },
    {
        "processExecutionId": "9e3e21e5-7e0a-4d9d-990d-2e4ffcb9554b"
    },
    {
        "processExecutionId": "e411a50b-4f3c-46d3-a9e5-3a7a4fa46dbb"
    },
    {
        "processExecutionId": "844d4e1e-8a1f-434f-a05e-7f08bc5a572e"
    },
    {
        "processExecutionId": "6f68e44f-12bc-42c3-8aba-95b28fe59a47"
    },
    {
        "processExecutionId": "68bad260-644b-4bbd-a91f-3e2bc583007f"
    },
    {
        "processExecutionId": "70ed1c16-6a0a-4bd8-8a78-3282fd677438"
    }
]
```

I didnt understand how to handle this.

I tried this way as well

```sql
select d.pid
from MyContainer d
where d.pid in (
   SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c.pid
   FROM MyContainer c
   WHERE c.ServiceName = 'myService'
   AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.Messages, {"ApiResponse":{"statusCode":400}}, true)
)
```

Then the subquery alone returns this structure

```
[
    "fabf7364-bef7-4170-bdcf-9ee0cc8df077",
    "48576688-1331-4742-a885-447028462bfc",
    "05257306-538a-467f-a546-f57bc79d4074",
    "907c8136-fb56-42ee-8d63-ecfd9a26384a",
    "69bcc177-e573-4261-8f34-069496ec6e6f",
    "9e3e21e5-7e0a-4d9d-990d-2e4ffcb9554b",
    "e411a50b-4f3c-46d3-a9e5-3a7a4fa46dbb",
    "844d4e1e-8a1f-434f-a05e-7f08bc5a572e",
    "6f68e44f-12bc-42c3-8aba-95b28fe59a47",
    "68bad260-644b-4bbd-a91f-3e2bc583007f",
    "70ed1c16-6a0a-4bd8-8a78-3282fd677438"
]
```

Still the same error.

Here is how my data looks

```
[{
    "id": "f01db56b-ec6c-407f-a590-2706f8588004",
    "processExecutionId": "29aaab8e-ae3b-4e53-b1b0-4078f3467cbb",
    "ServiceName": "Service1",
    "Status": "Success",
    "Messages": [
        {
            "Status": "Success",
            "Timestamp": "202303241819SS47",
            "ErrorCode": 0,
            "ApiResponse": null,
        },
        {
            "Status": "Success",
            "Timestamp": "202303241819SS19",
            "ErrorCode": 0,
            "ApiResponse": {
                "statusCode": 400,
                "error": "Error: Session no longer exists."
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "859f3421-db2e-4a8a-8d5c-77198a78a7ae",
    "processExecutionId": "29aaab8e-ae3b-4e53-b1b0-4078f3467cbb",
    "ServiceName": "Service2",
    "Status": "Success",
    "Messages": [
        {
            "Status": "Success",
            "Timestamp": "202303241819SS47",
            "ErrorCode": 0,
            "ApiResponse": null
        },
        {
            "Status": "Success",
            "Timestamp": "202303241819SS19",
            "ErrorCode": 0,
            "ApiResponse": null
        }
    ]
}]
```

As you can see there are same processExecutionId for the 2 items, but different services. I am trying to only service1 having apiresponse 400, and I need to get the data belongs to service2 for the same processExecutionId. So there are groups of processExecutionIds, but service names will differ.

I tried this query but it doesnt worked as well

```
SELECT c2.*
FROM mycontainer c1
JOIN c2 IN c1.Messages
WHERE c1.ServiceName = 'Service1'
    AND c2.ApiResponse.status = 400
    AND c2.ApiResponse.error IS NOT NULL
JOIN c3 IN mycontainer
WHERE c3.ServiceName = 'Service2'
    AND c3.processExecutionId = c1.processExecutionId
```

Comment: Add to your question on what is the sample document and what exactly the output you need

Comment: @Sandeep Thomas, Please share sample documents, it will be helpful for us to understand and write  query. Also it looks like you are trying to get pid from MyContainer through subquery and again fetching pid form same container.

Comment: You can't use the results of a query from one document to filter another document. You'll need to run two separate queries.